# I am getting 400 response for a http post request. How do I resolve this issue?

Tags: http-post

I have been trying to make a simple web request using python post data, the response ,
 `The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).`
The code below posts a request using python requests library. 400 response is received when executed. Could this issue be due to header syntax or format issues.

code:

```
headers = {
    'Host': 'host.url',
    'Content-Length': '1847',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua': '"Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, /',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'auth-key',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile': '?0',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform': '"Windows"',
    'Origin': 'origin.url',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
    'Referer': 'referer.url',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Connection': 'close',
}

data = {}
import json
json_object = json.dumps(data, indent = 4) 
response = requests.post('url', data=json_object ,headers=headers, verify=False)
print(response.text)
```